# Accessing parent component method from child

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on an angular app. I have a method in the parent component which returns a response.

```
parentComponent.ts:

myMethod(id) {
  //API call and return response on the basis of id
}
```

I have many child component for this parent component. I want to call this method from child component. While calling this method from child component I will pass an Id which will in turn call API and give response in child component. How can I call this parent component method from child component and get response in child component. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `@Output` in your child component. https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple example for calling parent method from child method:

```html
Parentcomponent.html

<app-child-component (parentFun)="parentFun()" ></app-child-component>

Parentcomponent.ts

parentFun(){
    alert("parent component function.");
  }

childcomponent.html

<button (click)="onClick()">
    click me, to Call parent component function.
  </button>

childcomponent.ts

export class ChildComponentComponent implements OnInit {
@Output("parentFun") parentFun: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(){
    this.parentFun.emit();
  }
}
```